# Нужно ли второе тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, спп

Требуется ли второе тире? Мы не будем затрагивать суициды людей, страдающих психическими заболеваниями – шизофренией, тяжелыми депрессиями, старческой деменцией, – а также тех, кого толкают к краю наркотики.
Думается, если его убрать - то последующая часть станет словно бы продолжением перечисления списка болезней (формально).

Answer (score 2):

*Мы не будем затрагивать суициды людей (каких?), **страдающих психическими заболеваниями – шизофренией, тяжелыми депрессиями, старческой деменцией**, а также тех (людей), **кого толкают к краю наркотики**.*

Второе тире не ставится, так как это не вставка, а обособленный ряд приложений, стоящий **перед запятой**.

ПРАВИЛА:

**Розенталь** (п. 10): http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается: ...если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая.

**ПАС (полный академический справочник)** http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

§ 65. Приложения отделяются **одиночным тире** (второе тире поглощается другим знаком или опускается): 4) если по условиям контекста после приложения стоит **запятая**: *Проходя вдоль своего вагона — **нашего временного жилища**, увидели мы в окне знакомую физиономию* (тире **поглощается запятой**, отделяющей деепричастный оборот);

Союз А ТАКЖЕ соединяет два дополнения, что видно из конструкции: *людей, а также тех (людей).* Первое дополнение определяется причастным оборотом с однородным рядом приложений, а второе относится к придаточному.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104382/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----).

Comment: Дублирую последний комментарий, чтобы о нём было известно: А желательно иметь хоть какое-то понятие, так как от этих 2 вариантов (вспомогательные примеры или только 3 вещи) сильно зависит пунктуация. В первом - тире с запятой или скобки, а во втором - запятая или тире с запятой. Подсказка именно про это предложение или в общем про однородный ряд?

Comment: Так что там у вас за решение?

Comment: Что там - у меня пока нет желания озвучивать, хотя я и собиралась это сделать.  Как-нибудь не здесь и не сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Тире однозначно нужно. Они с запятой ставятся по разным основаниям. Никакого "съедания" знаками друг друга не бывает.

Comment: кого слушать?))

Comment: @Татьяна Пичурина Если сомневаетесь, почитайте старые темы форума. Много раз тут спорили. Плюс ссылка на правило: http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=472 § 156.

Comment: @Sharon Вы путаете тёплое с мягким § 65. 4) и Розенталь дают примеры коротких предложений, где обособляемая часть стоит с краю. Ясно. что её не  обязательно отделять и запятой и тире.  Деепричастному обороту тире хватает. Но в вопросе сложное, длинное предложение со вставкой в середине. Розенталь об этих случаях пишет: "если возможно двоякое толкование фразы, ставится и то, и это". Татьяна Пичурина. как раз в такой ситуации: " последующая часть станет словно бы продолжением перечисления списка болезней (формально)".Так что Ваш формализм тут только вредит. При всём уважении, конечно

Comment: @Sharon Маленькая поправочка: здесь причастный оборот.

Comment: @Sharon Вы лучше выдохните — мой Вам совет. Как вижу ситуацию я: Вы сослались на постороннее правило с посторонними примерами, а теперь желаете добрать «веса» своему ответу, прося меня со своей стороны найти идеальный пример или идеальное правило прямо конкретно под предложение из вопроса. Чего ради я буду так заморачиваться? Ваш ответ меня не убедил. Моё мнение — парные знаки препинания должны быть закрыты. Хотите выглядеть убедительнее — найдите более сильные примеры для своего ответа. Не хотите — мне без разницы.

Comment: Извините, больше комментировать ваши ответы никогда не буду.  Кстати,  ваша риторика не совсем корректна: путаете тёплое с мягким, выдохните. Такая фразеология на форуме не приветствуются.