# Обособление однородного ряда приложений в середине предложения перед запятой

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены, приложение

В приведенном предложении  поставлено только одно тире перед запятой, второе тире опущено:

*Вот уж запахло **деревней ― дымом, дёгтем, баранками**, послышались звуки говора, шагов и колёс бубенчики;* [Л. Н. Толстой. Отрочество (1854)]

Это соответствует современным правилам? Нужна ссылка на правило (для распространенного приложения или ряда перед запятой), а также хорошо бы найти другие примеры.

Вопрос продолжает тему [Нужно ли второе тире?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458331/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5/458334?noredirect=1#comment471632_458334)

Comment: А как нашли пример?

Comment: Что значит как? Прочитала всего Л.Н. Толстого.

Comment: За 2 дня?)) Ну и скорость чтения...

Comment: Да, представьте, да еще кроме Толстого, были другие дела.

Comment: 1 страница в секунду? Только в "Война и мир" 1900 страниц.

Comment: Читать надо уметь.  Я раньше подбирала по этой теме материал (вставка или приложение), но брала его  из учебных книжек. Там были еще примеры, но все "фальшивые". То есть как наши педагоги делают: берут классика и составляют из его оригинального текста нужные предложения, которые соответствуют теме. Только этот пример  настоящим оказался.

Comment: А Розенталь тоже так делал: предложение Лермонтова и ещё один пример под вопросом.

Comment: Я считаю, что это некорректно. Но во времена Розенталя Интернета не было, искать примеры было сложнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведу правило, которое действовало в то время. [Ссылка](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=y69GAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA113&dq=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC,%20%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC,%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLibq5t9HnAhUF_CoKHUUqDEc4FBDoAQg4MAI#v=onepage&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C&f=false).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу обратить внимание на точку с запятой — в некоторых старых изданиях использована именно такая пунктуация.

Вот ещё несколько примеров, приведенных в той же книге по этому правилу:

> Он почитал за грех продавать хлеб — Божий дар, и в 40-м году, во время
>   всеобщего голода и страшной дороговизны, роздал окрестным помещикам и
>   мужикам весь свой запас. (Тургенев)
>
> Но сия любовь, способствуя успеху великого дела — избавлению
>   отечества, имела и несчастное следствие. (Карамзин)

Comment: Спасибо, интересно.  Это не Грот случайно? А в современных изданиях одно тире сохраняется? Кстати, У Розенталя есть похожее правило, только не для приложения, а для пояснительных слов. Недавно обсуждали.

Comment: Скорее всего, точка с запятой блокирует тире. Не захотел Толстой отделять приложение лишь запятой, поскольку в нём имеются свои запятые.

Comment: @Sharon Во всех современных изданиях, до которых я смог дотянуться (и в большинстве старых), одно тире и запятая после "баранками". И здесь тоже прослеживается связь с пояснениями ("то есть"). Это "Краткая русская грамматика" Лебедева (первый раз встречаю). Добавлю сейчас ссылку на гуглокниги в ответ — в комментарий не помещается.

Answer (score 2):

Правильное предложение [Л. Толстого](https://books.google.ee/books?id=HETgifb5KAIC&pg=PT10&lpg=PT10&dq=%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%83%D0%B6%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC,%20%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC,%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0,%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%81%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=PwfLr4un1G&sig=ACfU3U1YzY1ULHJOsGwJbjdHGMTOFq5_EQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMlZed2tHnAhXukYsKHWUlABoQ6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%83%D0%B6%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%2C%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%81%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8&f=false) выглядит так:
*Вот уж запахло деревней ― дымом, дёгтем, баранками, послышались звуки говора, шагов и колёс...* (Бубенчики — лишние.)

1. Вместо запятой при обособлении приложений может использоваться тире:

а) если перед приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить ***а именно***;
б) если приложение носит разъяснительный характер или нужно подчеркнуть его самостоятельность.

2. Второе тире опускается, если после обособленного приложения ставится запятая.

*Я надел свой новый жилет, хороший сюртук — подарок фабриканта, хорошенько причесал волосы и пошел в ликерную лавку моего папеньки* (Л. Толстой).

[Обособленные и необособленные приложения](https://books.google.ee/books?id=jSsqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%83%D0%B6%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC,%20%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC,%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0,%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%81%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=jpdoUgmWFw&sig=ACfU3U3FYaX11-2J1ZjIovcqziwKdlAw5Q&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAz8i709HnAhViiYsKHaHlDVUQ6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%83%D0%B6%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%2C%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%81%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8&f=false)

Comment: Римма, большое спасибо за ответ. Меня особенно интересуют примеры с обособлением однородных рядов перед запятой. Пожалуйста, пришлите, если встретятся.